# Reading and existing file in Xamarin withC#

Tags: android, file, xamarin

**This code works**:

```
string file = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "File.text");

File.ReadAllText(file);
```

Pretty straight-forward, but when I display the variable "file" using a Pizel 5 simulator I get a weird path: /data/user/0/com.companyname.aikidohours/files/.local/share/File.text. I can write new data to the file and read from it. but I now want to read from an existing file and I can't figure out where to put the file. Can someone tell where to put a text file full of basic information that I need to read from in Xamarin for adnroid?
Thanks
Todd

Comment: In the same folder? And there are other then LocalApplicationData. It is a quite normal path also.

Comment: Do you want to deploy this file as part of your project?   You can do that, but it won’t be writable.  You’ll have to copy it to a writable path first.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deploy that file with your application, you can add it to the 'Assets' folder inside your_project_name.Android project.
WARNING!!! File put in this folder are READONLY!
In case this is ok for you,this is the code to access the file:

```
using Xamarin.Essentials;

using (var reader = new StreamReader(await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("file_path")))
{
    string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```